# App to log me out of Gmail

Tags: android, gmail

It seems that once I have logged in to Gmail from an Android device, [Google does not want me to sign out](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/2991620?hl=en).

Is there an app that will let me do so?

Please note that I ***do not*** want to:
 - password protect the app (other than with my Gmail password)
 - change my Gmail password
 - remove Gmail from my Android device

After I sign out, if anyone picks up my phone and launches the Gmail app, they should see a standard Gmail login screen, just as they would on a factory fresh device.

Is there such an app?

Comment: Here is similar discussion https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/rUysp9-cQlQ which may help you.

Comment: My solution was to create a dummy google account that is my "main" phone account, and then log in log out using my second (real) gmail account.

Comment: Sounds great. Since I have already set up my main account, do you know if I can swap to your system without a factory reset?

Comment: I don't use Gmail, otherwise I could've tested this before speaking out. Anyhow, have you tried clearing data of Gmail from **Settings -> Apps (or All Apps) -> Gmail** to reset it (like factory fresh)? It shouldn't affect any email but the custom settings of Gmail. Neither should it be affecting any Google Account in your phone.

Comment: You can sign out from all active sessions on mobile and web from a browser pointed to gmail.com (scroll to the bottom and click on details)